# Laravel kills ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, crash, kill

I have this VPS where I have install Ubuntu and Laravel works fine on it. But today I realised that it didn't. I have created a CMS with a nice and easy administration which only use AJAX to POST and UPDATE/PATCH the content of the page.

When I create a Page in this CMS it works without problem.
When I EDIT a page in this CMS the AJAX request doesn't even reach the controller, the server get killed.

All the sites I got on the ubuntu server stops working, I get logged out of the SSH and I have to restart the server.
This is happening when I edit a page and an ajax request is sent to controller@update.

I tried to write die() at the top of the update method, but it still crashed.
I tried to remove the Request instance in the update method argument (update(Request $xxx)), but it still crashed.
I tried to make the code in the middleware to be a comment, but it still crashed.

I can’t find anything in /var/log/apache2/error.log, or any of the other logs either.

Summary: I can create pages but I cannot edit them, the server crash/totally dies.
It works perfectly on my local computer but not here.
I have 1 gb memory and 1 core cpu. I also tried to increase that to 4 gb memory and 2 core cpu. I also tried to use Swap on the ubuntu.

While I was writing this I found out that everything I try to update on the server (not only pages, maybe administrators, languages in the cms) the server dies, maybe some sql problem?

Please help me to solve this problem!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please provide Controller code...
If system crash, it most make some logs... Laravel, Apache or system log.
Did you turn error reporting in PHP?
hint:
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: error_reporting is on and I cannot see any error logs with useful information anywhere :(